# Possessive adjective "Juan y Antonio viven con su hermano."

Tags: posesivos

I was reading a sentence and asked to answer a True/False question:

> Juan y Antonio viven con **su** hermano.
>   The possessive adjective in bold is masculine and singular. True/False?

I thought that because Juan and Antonio make two people, and that they are the ones "owned" by their brother, I thought su would be the plural 3rd person i.e. "their" brother.

I thought the answer was false but it is actually true - the possessive adjective here in bold is masculine *and singular*.

I'm a bit confused.

Shouldn't the sentence be

> Juan y Antonio viven con **sus** hermano?

What is the difference between

> Juan y Antonio viven con **su** hermano.
>   Juan y Antonio viven con **sus** hermano.

because I thought the second sentence was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the number of the possesive. The first (su) is singular and the second (sus) is plural. They (Juan y Antonio) live with their brother (only one brother). For that reason you have to use the singular.

Examples:

- Juan y Antonio viven con su hermano (Juan and Antonio live with their brother). Hermano is singular.
- Juan vive con sus hermano**s** (Juan lives with his brother**s**). Hermanos is plural.

Answer (score 2):

Juan and Antonio have a brother.  We can talk about **their** brother (*su hermano*). "Brother" is a singular entity, so whatever modifier we put in front of "brother" / *hermano* (in this case "their" / *su*) will also be singular.

The subject, Juan and Antonio (=they) is plural, hence the choice "their" in English (instead of "his").  However, in Spanish, the possessive pronoun is always going to be **su**, regardless of whether the subject is singular ("he" / *él, ella*) or plural ("they" / *ellos, ellas*).

Let's step away from the possessive pronouns for a moment and look at this in action with a garden variety adjective.

> Some dogs have a short tail.
>
> Algunos perros tienen una cola cortita.

The subject (*perros*) and its modifier (*algunos*) are plural.  The object (*cola*) and its modifier (*cortita*) are singular.

(If I were your instructor, I wouldn't care whether you classified *su* in the exercise as "singular" correctly.  I'd care that you wrote a sentence that fit the family relationship, and I'd care that you understand these sorts of sentences.)